# Equivalent of PISA study for standardised assessment of skills on computational thinking and programming?

Tags: assessment, computational-thinking

My university wants to develop an assessment procedure in order to evaluate the general (not for a specific topic or course) skills on computational thinking and programming languages of our students when finishing their degree. I am aware of code repositories containing programming challenges, such as [ACM International Collegiate Programming Contest](https://icpc.baylor.edu/welcome.icpc) or [Euler](https://projecteuler.net/), that may be used for the assessment, but I was wondering if initiatives exist to define a common framework to assess these skills for computer science students.

I am thinking on something similar to the worldwide [PISA](http://www.oecd.org/pisa/) study (which evaluates performance on mathematics, science and reading by 15-year-old students) but adapted to the context of computer science (in particular computational thinking and programming skills). Are there any attempts to have this kind of standardised assessments?

Comment: I suspect that there are few answers appearing because there really aren't any such tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Educational Testing Service (ETS) Major Field Test for Computer Science](https://www.ets.org/mft/about/content/computer_science), a standardized multiple-choice test. Scores can be [compared to those at other institutions](https://www.ets.org/mft/scores/compare_data), presumably on a per question basis.

The ETS website includes some [sample problems](https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/MFT/pdf/mft_samp_questions_compsci.pdf), which include questions about pseudocode, cache variables, trees, graphs, combinatorics, and regular expressions. It looks similar to the CS GRE, which was [discontinued in 2013](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Codility](https://www.codility.com) or [Code Chef](https://www.codechef.com). I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but both are good for competitive assessment of programmers.